# .htaccess not accepting password

Tags: php, .htaccess

.htaccess code

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

`.htaccess` file and `.htpasswd` file present in the same place, when I access the URL it asking the username and password but page redirecting to `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: What does your error logs say?

Comment: i dont like to hard code this path,

Comment: actual, .htaccess, reading the file in the below location, but my file is in my project location.    (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : Could not open password file: C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/.htpasswd

Comment: you have to specify the full path in .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

> AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile:

*“The AuthUserFile directive sets the name of a textual file containing the list of users and passwords for user authentication. File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.”*

I’m pretty sure your `.htpasswd` file is *not* located directly under the server’s file system root – so give an absolute path from there.

(If you don’t know what the path from the server root is, you can look into PHP’s `$_SERVER` variable or try `realpath('.htpasswd')`

Comment: do u mean like this AuthUserFile realpath('.htpasswd')

Comment: I meant put that into a PHP script in the same directory, just to see the actual file system path – it does not belong into the .htaccess of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give full path in AuthUserFile. For example like this:

```
AuthUserFile "/var/www/DOMAIN/docs/admin/.htpasswd"
```

So find out the exact Doc Root Path from $_SERVER (or any other way).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look to Apache logs?

The `Internal Server Error` means Apache thinks something went wrong in your configuration, and it is highly probable that it put some log in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` of your server.

Look for it and you should have a pretty good idea about what went wrong.

Good luck.

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer...

Comment: .htaccess checking password file, but i am not placed here C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/, now how can i set the path for .htpasswd .

Answer (score 0):

`i dont like to hard code this path`

If that's the case create a symbolic link of `.htpasswd` in the $DOCUMENT_ROOT directory like this:

```
cd "\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\"
MKLINK \actual\path\of\.htpasswd .htpasswd
```

#### See here for: [How do I create a symbolic link in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7109/how-do-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-windows)